# Can't change the setting of VNC, such as resolution and depth

Tags: remote-desktop, resolution, vnc, vncserver

Usually, we typed vncserver -depth 24 -geometry 1920x1080 to generate a VNC session.
But at some point, The VNC session can be generated with only vncserver command, and the following option doesn't affect the result as below.

$ vncserver :3

New desktop is tk04:3

Starting applications specified in ~/.vnc/xstartup
Log file is tk04:3.log

I want to fix this because I want to change the resolution to 3840x1080 for the dual monitor.

Thanks.

Comment: check for configuration file in ~/.vnc, or /etc/. Do a `man vncserver` and see if that provides clues. Newer OSes start vncserver as a service. ~/.Xdefaults may also exist and contain clues.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the manual of vncserver indicate all of the options such as display resolutions, not the default. To the top of it, all other users are able to set there resolution and I was also able to. Thanks.